# How to build sub module with child modules of maven project

Tags: maven

Here's my project structure.

```
 ├── module_1
          ├── module_11
          ├── module_12
          ├── module_13
 ├── module_2
 ├── module_3
```

Now what I want is to build all the child modules of sub_module. I have the following 3 approaches.

1. specify these modules explicitly. This is not convenient when I have many sub modules under sub_module

   mvn package -pl module_1/module_11,module_1/module_12,module_1/module_13
2. Use -amd. The problem of this approach is that all the modules depends on module_1 will also be built, but I only want to build child modules under module_1.

   mvn clean package -pl module_1 -amd
3. Use -f. The problem of this approach is that I can not build module_1 together with other modules. e.g. how can I build module_1 with module_2 together.

   mvn clean package -f module_1

What I want is something like following so that it can build all the child modules under module_1 and module_2 as well.

```
mvn clean package -pl module_1,module_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there reason why you can't use `mvn clean package` directly on the sub module's pom.xml. (Unless there is something advanced here I did not know, this is the simplest solution.).

For your 3 point, I would create another aggregator pom which includes sub_module and module_2, and use `mvn package` on this newly created aggregator. (This is not good practice, every time you want different pairs of sub modules, you have to create new aggregator)

Comment: Just update the post, what I want is that one maven build command to build all the child modules under module_1 and module_2

Comment: @zjffdu Did you try -am switch instead of -amd switch. -am means also-make, -amd means also-make-dependents (which cause dependent projects to be build like you mentioned in question). You can try aggregator approach mentioned in the answer, if your build module list does not change frequently. Also check this page it contains good info https://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/